# Decrypting a user private key cert in keystore

Tags: storage, vpn, certificates

Would like to ask if it is possible to decrypt the user private key store found in android keystore.

I know that you need the `masterkey` to decrypt it. But is it possible to obtain the `masterkey` from a rooted android device?

Comment: the only known method is freeze RAM https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/f0711b733ba46efa9730a82c13e4ee7d66b39e37

Answer (score 2):

The Android Keystore (in code named `AndroidKeyStore`) uses on recent Google Android Devices the hardware based security of the ARM CPUs named Trusted Execution Environment (TEE).

Therefore the private keys are protected in a way that allows Android apps to use them (e.g. decrypt something using that private key) but you can't extract those keys, as the hardware compartment the code is executed in, has no export function.

Therefore even on rooted devices you can not get export or "decrypt" private and also symmetric keys that are stored in the Android Keystore. This means that apps using that keystore are bound to the device and you can't fully backup app data of such apps as the Android Keystore protected keys will always be missing.